# Reject Specific Database PostgreSQL User Authentication

Tags: postgresql, security, linux, redhat

Lets say I have two databases: Sales and Inventory

And two users: A and B

I want user A to be able to do: `psql sales B`

But user A must **not** be able to do: `psql inventory B`

Right now user A can access both of the above psql databases by logging in as user B, as done above.

Here's 3 options I've considered:

- Edit the `/opt/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` file

  - But, configuring that file creates tons of security issues
- Create a ~/.pgpass file for user A and B

  - For some reason I can't even get postgres to acknowledge the file's existence, even when I enter `~/.pgpass`'s contents as `\*:\*:\*:B:wrong_password`
- Create a PGPASSWORD environment variable

  - Not database specific

Comment: So A and B are OS users?  What do you mean by 'configuring that file creates tons of security issues'?  Are you sure that the `.pgpass` files are owned by the respective owners (how does this solve your issue anyway? `-W` will override a wrong stored PW) and the permissions are 0600, at most?

Comment: Yes, users A and B are RHEL users and have their own /home/A & /home/B areas with all that good stuff. The `pg_hba.conf` file is under the umbrella of what's considered "system configuration files", meaning they are controlled and closely monitored. Yes, `~/.pgpass` is 0600 & is owned by that user. That doesn't solve my `-W` or `--no-password` issue, and I'm not sure what to do with that either =/

Answer (score 1):

If those two databases are on the same cluster (beware of the PostgreSQL terminology, it's a name for an instance or installation or whatever you want), then you cannot prevent the users from logging in.  All databases on a [single cluster share the same users](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/database-roles.html):

> Database roles are conceptually completely separate from operating system users. In practice it might be convenient to maintain a correspondence, but this is not required. Database roles are global across a database cluster installation (and not per individual database).

As Neil McGuigan pointed out in his comment, this is not completely true - one can set `db_user_namespace` to have database specific user names.  I don't recommend using this, the reason is in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SECURITY):

> **Note:** This feature is intended as a temporary measure until a complete solution is found. At that time, this option will be removed.

Also, if user `B` knows the password of `a@databasea`, this cannot prevent him from logging in.

What you *can* do, however, is preventing user `A` from doing anything in `databaseB` by revoking every permission there might be, especially connecting to a database.  The background is that logging in to a *cluster* is not the same thing as connecting to a *database*.  Preventing [the latter is easy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-revoke.html):

```
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE databaseb FROM a; -- ALL means CONNECT, too
```

Please note that `pg_hba.conf` does its work also on the database level, so you can disallow connections there, too:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD
host    databasea       a               10.228.116.0/24         md5
host    databaseb       b               10.228.116.0/24         md5
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't fully explain: User `a` doesn't even have a database role on PostgreSQL. User a is accessing both databases by logging into them as user B (for your example): `psql databasea b` and `psql databaseb b`. Both of which user a can do. Here's the contents of the `pg_hba.conf` file that I can't change: `local   all   all  (blank)   trust`. Host doesn't apply because we are ssh-ing to the boxes.

Comment: @dezso actually you can have per-database users instead of per-cluster users. See db_user_namespace setting in postgresql.conf

Comment: @Everlight so you want to prevent an OS user from logging into the DB completely?  It sounds like you want to jail him - but then it's not a database administration issue.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan thanks for pointing it out - I've updated my answer.

Comment: @dezso Yeah, kinda, I want to prevent an OS user from logging into databasea and allow them to log into databaseb as a different OS user.

Comment: @dezso it's been a "temporary" measure for 14 years. It's pretty permanent by now.